# After applying xsl on a xml file, it shows the contents after showing the table

Tags: xml, xslt

I am totally new to xml and xsl so I am having some difficulties to make my xml file look the way I wanted it to be. Basically the problem is that the table shows up correctly with all the stuff inside but the contents of the xml are also shown after the table. So i always have a table followed by all the data from xml. And i am testing my xml file on Firefox 16.0.2.

Here is a portion of my xml file.

```
<root>
  <name id = "content_here">
    <first> Cathy </first>
    <last> Claires </last>
  </name>
  ... more names down here
</root>
```

and I am trying to display it in a tabular format on Firefox and this is what I did for the xsl file.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
      <html>
       <body>
         <table>
           <tr>
             <th> id </th> 
             <th> first name </th> 
             <th> last name </th>
           </tr>
           <xsl:for-each select="name"> 
            <tr>
             <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> </td>
             <td> <xsl:value-of select="first"/> </td>
             <td> <xsl:value-of select="last"/> </td>
           </tr>
           </xsl:for-each>  
</table>        

<xsl:apply-templates/>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Anyone can give me a hint on how to get rid of the extra content after my table? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsl:apply-templates` instruction causes all the node children of your template context (here the `root` element) to be slung through the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). Removing it from your stylesheet should remove the content.

Note there's a better way of doing this though actually using the `xsl:apply-templates` rule.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th> id </th> 
            <th> first name </th> 
            <th> last name </th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>        
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name"> 
    <tr>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="@id"/> </td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="first"/> </td>
      <td> <xsl:value-of select="last"/> </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here `xsl:apply-templates` is used to apply template matching to the children of `root` inside your `table`. When a `name` element is matched, a `tr` is created. This is generally better practice than using `xsl:for-each`.